# How to select random numbers from a given list in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, random, octave

How to select random numbers from a given list of data

I can create a list of **5 random numbers between 50 and 100** using the code below but how can I have it randomly select numbers from a dataset of values example **dataset=[10;20;25;111;14];**

```
amtofNumbers=5; %amount of numbers
a = 50;
b = 100;
r = (b-a).*rand(amtofNumbers,1) + a
```

I'm using octave 3.8.1 which works with matlab .

Comment: You could replace those 4 lines with `randi([50, 100], 1, 5)`

Comment: @huntj: Not really, randi gives him integers, his codes produces doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a random index for dataset. Below I select 6 random entries from your dataset:

```
dataset = [10;20;25;111;14];
idx = randi (numel (dataset), 6, 1)
dataset (idx)
```

gives:

```
idx =

   4
   4
   2
   5
   3
   5

dataset (idx)
ans =

   111
   111
    20
    14
    25
    14
```

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab (Statistics Toolbox), [`randsample`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) does exactly that:

```
result = randsample(dataset, n, true);
```

where `n` is the desired ouput size and `true` indicates sampling with replacement.